# Google ios sign up move to MainTabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

The good news is that the whole sign up part works great but I can't seem to get the move from the AppDelegate.swift part to the MainTabBarController (the part of the app I am trying to move to) in the simulator the error I am getting is that value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'dismiss' and whenever I try to move the code to a different part of the app to the signup part it doesn't work I have to include it in the AppDelegate

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,   GIDSignInDelegate {



func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let err = error {
        print("Failed to Login to Google", err)
        return
    }

    print("Successfully logged into Google", user)

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    guard user.authentication.idToken != nil else {return}
    guard user.authentication.accessToken != nil else {return}
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

    Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to Login Google user to Firebase db", error)
            return
        }

        print("Successfull Login")
    }

    guard let mainTabBarController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? MainTabBarController else { return }

    mainTabBarController.setupViewControllers()

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

var window: UIWindow?
```

Final note I am doing this project with swift code only no storyboard part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you don't have to keep it in `AppDelegate` you can add it in any vc just with delegate conformance like

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate,GIDSignInUIDelegate {
```

---

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.read")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() 
}
```

---

Second you have to do the move inside `Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData` as it's asynchronous

```
Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("Failed to Login Google user to Firebase db", error)
        return
    } 
     print("Successfull Login") 
     let mainTab = mainTabBarController() 
     mainTab.setupViewControllers()
     self.window?.rootViewController = mainTab
}
```

In `AppDelegate` use

```
self.window?.rootViewController = mainTab
```

In any vc use

```
(UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.rootViewController = mainTab
```